# jQuery: int value split as an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, int

I have a function in my script and the first parameter is an int value.

```
thisIsMyFunction(4,"foo");
```

I would like to create an array with that int value, so in this case, it should create an array with 4 items in it, like so:

```
var intArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

And so on:

```
thisIsMyFunction(8,"foo");
var intArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

I am a beginner in javascript, so I hope you can help me solve my issue ;)
Thanks

Comment: why do you need "foo" in the functions?

Comment: what output you want just tell it,no more lines.State in 1 line what output you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function thisIsMyFunction(count, string) {
    var intArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        intArray.push(i);
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
function test(length,string)
{
var array=[];
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
array.push(i);

}
return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through and fill the array values as below.

```
function thisIsMyFunction(count, string) {
intArr = [];
for (var i=0;i<functionVal;i++){
    intArr[i] = i;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function thisIsMyFunction(num, str){
   var arr = [];
   for(i=0; i < num; i++){
      arr.push(i);
   }
   console.log(arr);
   return arr;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't reference anything in the DOM, why does it need to be in the `onload` handler?

Answer (score 1):

```
function thisIsMyFunction(num, line){
    var intArray = [];
    for( var i=0; i<num; i++ ){
        intArray.push(i);
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Array.prototype.repeat= function(what, L){
 while(what < L) this[what]= what++;
 return this;
}
var A= [].repeat(0, 4);

alert(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the array size to the integer that is being passed and just increment the array items.

Comment: Providing a small sample would be useful.